# StringReplace with a string containing a superscripted expression

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a list with strings:

`list = {"USA", "EU", "BRICS", "OECD", "NAFTA"};`

Now I want to use `StringReplace`to add a footnote with `Superscript`:

`StringReplace[list, "EU" -> Superscript["EU", "Footnote"]]`

but the outcome is
[image]

What is the problem here?

Comment: `StringReplace` replaces within strings and your replacement does not procude a string. Use `ReplaceAll` if you want to replace a whole string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic example from the documentation of [`StringReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html)

> Replace every occurrence of "ab" with "X":
>
> ```
> StringReplace["abbaabbaa", "ab" -> "X"]
>
> (*XbaXbaa*)
> ```

So `StringReplace` doesn't replace whole strings, but rather patterns *within* strings themselves.  Since strings are atomic in *Mathematica*, this allows you to sidestep, for example, first converting a string to a list of its characters (with [`Characters`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Characters.html)) and then going about your manipulations that way.

Since you're not working with a single string, I would use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) as

```
{"USA", "EU", "BRICS", "OECD", "NAFTA"} /. "EU" -> Superscript["EU", "Footnote"]
```

> {"USA", Superscript["EU","Footnote"], "BRICS", "OECD", "NAFTA"}

Answer (score 2):

You can post-process the output to remove the heads `StringExpression`:

```
StringReplace[list, "EU" -> Superscript["EU", "Footnote"]] /.
    StringExpression->Identity
```

[image]

```
StringReplace[list, 
  "EU" -> Superscript["EU", Style["Footnote", 16, Red, FontFamily -> "Felipa"]]] /. 
  StringExpression -> Identity
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can wrap the rhs of the replacement rule with `ToString[#,StandardForm]&`

```
StringReplace[list, 
 "EU" -> ToString[Superscript["EU", "Footnote"], StandardForm]]
```

[image]

```
StringReplace[list, 
  "EU" -> ToString[Superscript["EU",  Style["Footnote", 16, Red, FontFamily -> "Felipa"]], 
   StandardForm]]
```

[image]

The second method works as is for replacing parts of strings:

```
list2 = {"USA", "EUROPE", "BRICS", "OECD", "NAFTA"};
StringReplace[list2, "EU" -> ToString[Superscript["EU", "Footnote"], StandardForm]]
```

[image]

```
StringReplace[list2, 
 "EU" -> ToString[Superscript["EU", Style["Footnote", 16, Red, FontFamily -> "Felipa"]], 
   StandardForm]]
```

[image]

For the first method to work we need to change the replacement rule in `ReplaceAll` to

```
rule = StringExpression -> (StringJoin[ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ {##}] &);
```

Then

```
StringReplace[list2, "EU" -> Superscript["EU", "Footnote"]] /. rule
```

[image]

```
StringReplace[list2,  "EU" -> 
  Superscript["EU", Style["Footnote", 16, Red, FontFamily -> "Felipa"]]] /. rule
```

[image]